# New DateTime value in C# with possible 0 values

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert string values to datetime in C# but have run into an issue.

Here is a simplified code example:

```
string[] dates = {"19920000", "20001012", null, "19980605"}

foreach (var registeredDate in dates) 
{
    if (registeredDate != null)
    {
        var year = Int32.Parse(registeredDate.Substring(0, 4));
        var month = Int32.Parse(registeredDate.Substring(4, 2));
        var day = Int32.Parse(registeredDate.Substring(6, 2));
        var formattedRegisteredDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        return formattedRegisteredDate
    }
}
```

When the string only contains the year, and month and day is 0, I get an error when I try to create a new `DateTime`.

What is a possible solution to this? And is there a better way to convert the string to a datetime?

Comment: Why `Substring(0, 4)` and not  `Substring(0, 3)`?

Comment: @Elec1 because year has 4 digits, not 3.

Comment: _"And is there a better way to convert the string to dateTime?"_ -  yes, DateTime.Parse methods. Though in this case it is not applicable - 0 is not a valid value for month and day in .NET.

Comment: Is this really the format you get the date values in? Blame whoever provides dates in a non-standard format.

Comment: If the month and day are not specified, which date in the given year do you want to use? Just detect month and day being zero and substitute with your desired default values (e.g. month=1 and day=1)

Comment: `var dates = ["19920000", "20001012", null, "19980605"].` is not valid C#!

Comment: How about `DateTime.TryParseExact(registeredDate, new[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy0000"}, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out var parsedDate)`.

Comment: @Guru Stron sorry my bad. I wrongly remembered the second parameter to be the index of the last character of the substring and not the length.

Comment: @phuzi what if only day or month is `00`? Though OP has not specified if this is a possibility.

Comment: I agree with @phuzi here - `DateTime.TryParseExact` is the way to go, but it's up for the OP to decide what they want to do in cases of invalid dates (such as day or month being 0, or whatever)

Comment: @PMF I agree, this really isn't the optimal format to get the dates

Comment: @phuzi you are absolutely correct, I am writing both c sharp and react at the same time so I mixed them up a little. 
TryParseExact did the job! Thank you so much!
You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be easily able to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0) by specifiying the known formats that you're dealing with. Any unknown formats or otherwise invcalid values will be ignored.

```cs
    var dates = new[] { "19920000", "20001012", null, "19980605", "20230025", "19770300"};
    
    var validFormats = new[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy0000", "yyyy00dd", "yyyyMM00"};

    foreach (var registeredDate in dates)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(registeredDate, validFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out var parsedDate))
        {
            yield return parsedDate;
        }
    }
```

The values returned be this are:

- 1992-01-01 00:00:00
- 2000-10-12 00:00:00
- 1998-06-05 00:00:00
- 2023-01-25 00:00:00
- 1977-03-01 00:00:00

If there's only a partial date default values for the missing parts will be used i.e. 19920000 becomes 1992-01-01 00:00:00